# can i embed a private file of google drive api on my website? (the file has read permission of domain the my website)

Tags: html, google-api, google-drive-api

the file has read permissions for my domain

[image]

but when embedding the file on my google website
reject the embed

[image]

code of iframe

```
 <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/172YjAlA4ZtXzaaHGXORRX-687k78Rsra/preview" width="640" height="480">
```

I appreciate any help, and if you ask me why I want to show a private file on my website, it is because there is a login through which I only let my users enter

Comment: What is the data that you need to show? How many files do you need to show? If its simple then there are some workarounds, but if you are talking about many files then you may require a server to make calls to the API and then serve the data in another format.

Comment: Thanks bro for answering, if there are many files and they are going to be uploaded constantly, can you explain your solution a little more

Comment: You would need your own server I believe. Again it depends a lot on what you are trying to do exactly, which you haven't given very many details. Though I believe the answer to your specific question is below so you should accept it. You cannot embed a private file. If you have another question you should open a new question. Though maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for general questions about how to design your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can not embed a private google drive on your website because in order to access that drive a user would need to have permission to it.

You are probably using the webContentLink as the link you are trying to display there is also no way to send authorization in the form of an access token along with this link.  THe user themself must have access to the file to be able to download it.

You could try creating a sharable link manually on the Google Drive website and use that link you can set that link to be valid for anyone with the link.  But this will be a manual thing as far as i know you can not create these types of links though the website.

Comment: Can you recommend another solution to me, for my project ?, the idea is to upload, view , documents but host them in some service as drive